# Angular 10 Compile Error "error NG8001: 'mat-card-title' is not a known element:

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I am having an compile error, where when I go to type ng serve to view my changes locally, I am getting the following error for all of the imported modules on all of my components.

```
1. If 'mat-card-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

22                     <mat-card-title>Register</mat-card-title>
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/landing-page/landing-page.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component LandingPageComponent.
```

I know that this occurred after I pulled from another branch in my git repository, and that a new folder was added to my project called "node_modules", before that everything was fine. This wasn't happening before, so What could I do to alleviate this issue?

Do I need to import the module again into the individual components .ts files?

**Screenshot of console error :**

[image: Screenshot of console error]

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't check the `node_modules` folder into source control. `package.json` and `package-lock.json` is all you need. If you delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again it should be solved. (both package-lock and node_modules will be recreated after running the install command, just make sure to include node_modules in your .gitignore file).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `npm install` to install the new package added.
If the problem persist you need to install angular material `ng add @angular/material` and then an `npm install`, and for the router problem try this link [Angular router-outlet not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502701/angular-router-outlet-not-recognized)